# Uploading Images in Browser using react issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image

I'm trying to make the user upload several images to the browser using React (then save them of course to a server).

The problem is when I click choose image sometimes it work and sometimes not. Same for showing the images
Here is my code:

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([]);
const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false);

const fileSelectedHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    const files = selectedFiles;
    files.push(event.target.files[0]);
    setSelectedFiles(files);
    setIsSelected(true);
    console.log(selectedFiles);
}

const fileUploadHandler = () => {
    axios.post('http://')
}

return (
    <div className="container">
        <p>Please Enter Category name: </p>
        <TextField
            id="standard-multiline-flexible"
            label="Name"
            multiline
            rowsMax={4}
            variant="filled"
            color="secondary"
            value={name}
            onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)}
        />
        <p>Please Enter Category Description: </p>
        <TextField
            id="standard-multiline-flexible"
            label="Description"
            multiline
            rowsMax={4}
            variant="filled"
            color="secondary"
            value={description}
            onChange={(event) => setDescription(event.target.value)}
        />
        <input type="file" onChange={fileSelectedHandler}/>
        
        {
            selectedFiles.length > 0 ?
            
                <div className="row">
                    {
                        selectedFiles.map((file, index) => {
                                console.log(file, index);
                                return (
                                    <div className="column">
                                        <img className="added_images" width="100%" src={URL.createObjectURL(file)} thumbnail />
                                    </div>
                                )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            :
                null
        }
    </div>
)
```

and here is my styling:

```
 * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
}
  
/* Clear floats after image containers */
.row::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

When I debugged The `selectedFiles` hook contains all the files I uploaded. BUT the problem it is not triggering the render. Why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here issue is you are assigning whole `selectedFiles` to `files` like following

```
const files = selectedFiles;
```

This will also assign reference of `selectedFiles` to `files` const so after pushing new value to array when you try to update `selectedFiles` with `files` both array reference will be same so react will not trigger re-render.

To solve this try to shallow copy array like below:-

```
const files = [...selectedFiles];
```

Or when updating array, update it with spread operators like below:-

```
setSelectedFiles([...files]);
```

Or you can directly update your array state like below without copying it in new constant

```
const fileSelectedHandler = (event) => {
    setSelectedFiles(prevSelected => [...prevSelected, event.target.files[0]]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Priyank Kachhela. This solved my problem